# how to detect that the call is answered and send some numbers after answering the call?

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application i added an intent so that the app can call a special number :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "0123456789"));
startActivity(intent);
```

and created an event listener that if ringing finished the event is calling :

```
private PhoneStateListener listener = new PhoneStateListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if (incomingNumber != null || incomingNumber.isEmpty()){
            Log.i("Phone State", "incomingNumber:"+state);
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    if (incomingNumber.isEmpty()) {
                        Log.i("PhoneStateListener", "void");
                        Log.d("Checking---->", TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
                    } else {
                        Log.i("PhoneStateListener", "not void");
                        Log.d("Checking---->", TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
                    }
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
    }
    }

};
```

The question is that after ringing finished,app should call some number that the user can listen a special music but i do not know that how can do this work programmatically in android.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Create a boolean variable e.g. callFinished
- in the call function set it to false
- ring the second number to listen to music when is true.